# How to write sentry-debug-meta.properties file

Tags: android, terminal, proguard, android-proguard, sentry

This is a part of [Sentry.io installation guide](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/android/#proguard-uuids):

> ### ProGuard UUIDs
>
> After ProGuard files are generated you will need to
>   embed the UUIDs of the ProGuard mapping files in a properties file
>   named `sentry-debug-meta.properties` in the assets folder. The Java SDK
>   will look for the UUIDs there to link events to the correct mapping
>   files on the server side.
>
> `sentry-cli` can write the `sentry-debug-meta.properties` file for you:
>
> ```
> sentry-cli upload-proguard \
>     --android-manifest app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml \
>     --write-properties app/build/intermediates/assets/release/sentry-debug-meta.properties \
>     --no-upload \
>     app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
> ```

I installed `sentry-cli` with the help of its [installation guide](https://docs.sentry.io/cli/installation/) on my **Mac Os** but I don't know how to execute the command lines.
 I tried to right-click on AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio and click on **Open in terminal** and execute `sentry-cli upload-proguard AndroidManifest.xml` but ّI got this error:

```
warning: proguard mapping 'AndroidManifest.xml' was ignored because it does not contain any line information.
> compressing mappings
> uploading mappings

error: An organization slug is required (provide with --org)
```

How should I execute these commands to write `sentry-debug-meta.properties` file?

Comment: You are meant to run the command in any command line interface you are using.

Answer (score 0):

open your `sentry-cli` file and add the following fields:

```
defaults.project = your-project
defaults.org = your-org
auth.token = YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN
```